# Windows 8.1 AdControl for Universal Apps (Phone and Desktop)

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I get the following error compiling my new universal app for Windows Phone and Desktop version 8.1:

```
    The SDK "MSAdvertisingXaml, Version=8.1" cannot be referenced alongside SDK(s) "MSAdvertisingXaml, Version=6.1", as they all belong to the same SDK product Family "Microsoft.Advertising". Please consider removing references to other SDKs of the same product family.
```

They both use the same tool, AdControl, and it was running phone while I built the Windows Phone side of the app.  Once I dropped the same control into the Windows Desktop side of the app, I get this error.  I can't get ANYTHING to return when I Google the error message.  What is the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the top portion of the list within your "Solution Explorer" control (of MS Visual Studio - my version is 2013), look for a "References" section.  Simply delete the 6.1 item, as you want the latest version of the AdControl, which should work with both sides of your universal app.